# ElasticSearch POST with json search body vs GET with json in url

Tags: search, post, elasticsearch, get

According to the ES documentation, those 2 search request should get the same results:

GET

```
http://localhost:9200/app/users/_search?source={"query": {"term": {"email":"foo@gmail.com"}}}
```

POST

```
http://localhost:9200/app/users/_search
```

Post body :

```
{
    "query":  {
         "term": {
               "email":"foo@gmail.com"
          }
    }
}
```

But the first one gives no result while the second one gives me the expected result. I use ES version 0.19.10
Did anybody else have the same behavior ? Is this a bug ?

Answer (score 35):

`source` is not a valid query string argument according to [URI Search](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-uri-request.html)

Elasticsearch allows three ways to perform a search request...

**GET with request body:**

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/app/users/_search" -d '{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "email": "foo@gmail.com"
    }
  }
}'
```

**POST with request body:**

[Since not all clients support GET with body, POST is allowed as well.](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html#search-request-body)

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/app/users/_search" -d '{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "email": "foo@gmail.com"
    }
  }
}'
```

**GET without request body:**

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/app/users/_search?q=email:foo@gmail.com"
```

or (if you want to manually URL encode your query string)

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/app/users/_search?q=email%3Afoo%40gmail.com"
```

Comment: Yeah, for some reason, you can wrap the query in `_source` when performing a GET request, but not on POST. Go figure. Thanks for clearing this up, it saved me a lot of documentation readup.

Comment: Hi, I need to use POST to run a search query. The query is automatically generated and I am worried that if I made an error in the code, the query will update/create some documents. Is it possible to screw something up when you run _search with POST?

Comment: Hi, is it possible to use an and operator in the get request without a body to provide multiple parameter filters?

Comment: What are the pros and cons of each alternative?

Answer (score 3):

You should URL encode your query in the first case:

```
http://localhost:9200/app/users/_search?source=%7b%22query%22%3a+%7b%22term%22%3a+%7b%22email%22%3a%22foo%40gmail.com%22%7d%7d%7d
```

Answer (score 2):

The above answers are not compatible with the Elastic search Version 6.0 and above.The ES introduced Strict Content type check from the version 6.0.
The link explains it:
https://www.elastic.co/blog/strict-content-type-checking-for-elasticsearch-rest-requests.
For curl, need to add -H'Content-Type: application/json' to the command line of any request that has a JSON body