# Elasticsearch not returning results for aggregate query but returns results for other queries

Tags: elasticsearch

hi I'm new to elastic search and when i try a aggregate query it is not returning any results.

```
http://localhost:9200/contract/_search?search_type=count
    {
      "aggregations": {
        "status_cons": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "data.policyStatus",
            "size": 0
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Note: this is just one of the queries that i had tried ,I have give size as 0 with the query and remove the search type ,added a query term with match_all etc

found out this is a bug in the head plugin. GET method doesn't work using the head plugin.

Related dicussion :[Different result when using GET/POST in elastic search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12195017/different-result-when-using-get-post-in-elastic-search)

[no results for aggregation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/71d71.png)

Comment: Can you put your whole query here so that it will let us know what you have tried so far

Answer (score 2):

it worked at last !!!!! .please use a POST request when using the elastic search head plugin it .

Comment: Then where you were putting your query?It should be a POST request. Haven't you gone through the documentation?

Comment: I was using a Get request instead of a POST and I did take a look at the  documentation as well and GET is a valid method  refer:  https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search.html   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14339696/elasticsearch-post-with-json-search-body-vs-get-with-json-in-url